# [Vim][Markdown] How to disable url folding?

Tags: vim, markdown

I have some issue with default markdown format in vim. Whenever I try to write:

```
[this](https://real-link-here)
```

Vim will try to fold it into

```
this
```

I need to enter `visual` mode to see full text, which is pretty annoying.
Screenshot: [image]

Is there anyway to turn off that feature? Thanks.

Comment: Check the value of  `concealcursor` option. To make text in current line unconcealed try: `set concealcursor-=n`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This works for me `set conceallevel=0` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9604347/2490986) . Or if you use `indentLine` plugin, use this `let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0` from [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/how-do-i-prevent-vim-from-hiding-symbols-in-markdown-and-json#comment23465_7263)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on `vim.stackexchange.com`.